# What would I call this triangle next to the Task-SubTask?

Tags: task-list

[image: Subtask and task]

I'm looking for the correct terminology for the little triangle next to the task that will display the subtask.

Comment: Expander, maybe?

Comment: That's a very good answer! Someone here suggested play button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would call it an "Expander", based on the functionality it provides.  Although in this case it is used for Tasks, that particular type of UI control exists in many other UIs, including the Windows Explorer:

[image: Windows Exploere screen cap]

In that case, and in many others, the functionality it provides is to expand a view of child/sub items.

So... Expander.

I have no idea what the official Microsoft name for that control is.

Answer (score 2):

In fact , I don't know if this arrow has a specific name or not ? ,but usually, I tried to call something based on its functionality or what it denote to ?.

So This arrow denotes to the `multi-level parent task` that can `collapse` as your first image to hide related sub-tasks or `expanded` as the second image to show related subtasks.

Also to build your multi-level task structure in Task List, you can use the above ribbon by using `indent` (move the task down level), `outdent` (move the task up level) option

[image]

So if you can't find an official name for this arrow, you can call it based on its functionality as `Task Grouping arrow` or `Multi-Level task arrow` or `Parent task arrow` !